# VW Jetta transmission fluid

Tags: vw, transmission-fluid

I have a 2012 VW Jetta SEL 2.5L car.  I changed out my transmission fluid- I used a BOSCH product- Ravenol T-W8-1L ATF fluid.  Due to an error of mine- about 1 Quart of AFT fluid leaked out and I need to add it back, but I am out of the Ravenol product.

My question is:  Can I top off my fluid with another product?  Say a VW factory ATF?  Would this cause any problems?
Brad

Comment: Assuming the Ravenol fluid meets the same industry standards as the VW fluid, there should be no issues.  I'm sure that VW doesn't actually make any fluids but rather has fluid branded for them.  For all we know Ravenol makes it for VW.

Comment: @jwh20 does Bosch make their fluids or are they rebranded...

Comment: @SolarMike I don't know who makes VW fluids.  Generally those sort of things are proprietary.

Comment: Actually they are often not...just check the oil standard and then search for that..the are something like 'sae 12e' if its compatible with that then you can use it..

Comment: Which transmission do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You can top off with any fluid which meets VW factory specs.  VW has several suppliers of transmission fluid, but I have not seen Ravenol listed as one of them.  A major point of fluid specs is to ensure that added fluids are compatible with what is in there already.